# System.MissingMethodException - Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

Tags: c#, assemblies, missingmethodexception

I'm developing plugin based application using MEF2 - System.Composition.

My shell is targeting **.NET Core 5.0** (assembly name: PI.exe).

My Infrastructure library contains interfaces, class and extensions for communication and discovery dependencies between Shell and Plugins. Library is targeting **.NET Standard**
(for the sake of compatibility with the .NET Framework) (assembly name: PI.Core.dll).

And finally we have the plugin library it can be targeting .core, .standard, .framework.

For this purpose Plugin (assembly name: MyPlugin.Core.dll) is targeting **.NET Core 5** and reference to *Microsoft.Data.SqlClient* package.
When i running plugin i'm getting error:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception.
 ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Security.CodeAccessPermission System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory.CreatePermission(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState)'.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.CreateExecutePermission()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..cctor() in H:\tsaagent1\_work\18\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlConnectionHelper.cs:line 21
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor() in H:\tsaagent1\_work\18\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlConnectionHelper.cs:line 29
   at MyPlugin.Core.ExecuteQuery(String name) in C:\PI\MyPlugin.Core\MyPluginSql.cs:line 28
```

I tried diffrent targeting always had same exception.

Dumb of loaded modules from VS:

```
| NAME | VERSION |
| -------- | -------------- |
|Accessibility.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly||
|ControlzEx.dll|4.04.0.50|
|DevExpress.Mvvm.dll|20.02.0.0|
|DevExpress.Mvvm.UI.dll|20.02.0.0|
|DevExpress.Mvvm.v20.2.DynamicTypes.292c7474-81c7-4780-8d03-e4e7d5ee0da4||
|DirectWriteForwarder.dll|5,0,821,31506 @Commit: c3afd220b9380b3b329e7eddc63224d74e6f25fe|
|FileHelpers.dll|3.05.0.0|
|H.NotifyIcon.dll|1.00.18.0|
|Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification.dll|1.00.18.0|
|**MyPlugin.Core.dll**|**1.00.0.0**|
|MahApps.Metro.dll|2.04.7.2|
|MaterialDesignColors.dll|2.00.1.2556|
|MaterialDesignThemes.MahApps.dll|0.01.7.2556|
|MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.dll|4.01.0.2556|
|**Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll**|**3.00.21159.1**|
|Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll|5.00.20.51904|
|Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll|5.00.20.51904|
|Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine.dll|5.00.20.51904|
|Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll|5.00.20.51904|
|Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables.dll|5.00.20.51904|
|Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.dll|5.00.20.51904|
|Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll|5.00.20.51904|
|Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.dll|5.00.20.51904|
|Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll|5.00.20.51904|
|Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll|5.00.20.51904|
|Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll|5.00.20.51904|
|Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.dll|5.00.20.51904|
|Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.dll|5.00.20.51904|
|Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.dll|5.00.20.51904|
|Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll|5.00.20.51904|
|Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration.dll|5.00.20.51904|
|Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.dll|5.00.20.51904|
|Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug.dll|5.00.20.51904|
|Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll|5.00.20.51904|
|Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.dll|5.00.20.51904|
|Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource.dll|5.00.20.51904|
|Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions.dll|5.00.20.51904|
|Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll|5.00.20.51904|
|Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll|5.00.20.51904|
|Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.NetCoreApp.dll|16.10.10610.2|
|Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfTap.dll|16.10.31313.356|
|Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.dll|1.01.19.35512|
|mscorlib.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|netstandard.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|**PI.Core.dll**|**1.00.0.0**|
|**PI.dll**|**1.00.0.0**|
|PresentationCore.dll|5.00.821.31506|
|PresentationCore.resources.dll|5.00.821.31506|
|PresentationFramework-SystemCore.dll|5.00.821.31506|
|PresentationFramework-SystemData.dll|5.00.821.31506|
|PresentationFramework-SystemXml.dll|5.00.821.31506|
|PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll|5.00.821.31506|
|PresentationFramework.dll|5.00.821.31506|
|PresentationFramework.resources.dll|5.00.821.31506|
|System.Buffers.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Collections.Concurrent.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Collections.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Collections.Immutable.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Collections.Specialized.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.ComponentModel.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Composition.AttributedModel.dll|5.00.220.61120|
|System.Composition.Hosting.dll|5.00.220.61120|
|System.Composition.Runtime.dll|5.00.220.61120|
|System.Composition.TypedParts.dll|5.00.220.61120|
|System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll|5.00.20.51904|
|System.Console.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Core.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|**System.Data.Common.dll**|**5.00.821.31504**|
|**System.Data.dll**|**5.00.821.31504**|
|System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Diagnostics.EventLog.dll|5.00.321.7212|
|System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.dll|5.00.321.7212|
|System.Diagnostics.Process.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Drawing.Common.dll|5.00.421.11614|
|System.Drawing.Primitives.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.IO.FileSystem.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.IO.Packaging.dll|5.00.20.51904|
|System.IO.Pipes.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Linq.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Linq.Expressions.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Memory.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Net.Primitives.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Net.Requests.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Net.WebClient.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Numerics.Vectors.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.ObjectModel.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Private.CoreLib.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Private.DataContractSerialization.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Private.Uri.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Private.Xml.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Reactive.dll|5.00.0.1|
|System.Reflection.Emit.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Reflection.Metadata.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Reflection.Primitives.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Runtime.CompilerServices.VisualC.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Runtime.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Runtime.Extensions.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Runtime.Loader.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Runtime.Numerics.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|**System.Security.AccessControl.dll**|**5.00.821.31504**|
|System.Security.Claims.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|**System.Security.Permissions.dll**|**5.00.20.51904**|
|System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Text.Json.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Threading.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Threading.Overlapped.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Threading.Tasks.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Threading.Thread.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Transactions.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Transactions.Local.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.dll|5.00.821.31506|
|System.Windows.Extensions.dll|5.00.20.51904|
|System.Windows.Forms.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Windows.Forms.Primitives.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|System.Xaml.dll|5.00.821.31506|
|System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll|5.00.821.31504|
|UIAutomationProvider.dll|5.00.821.31506|
|UIAutomationTypes.dll|5.00.821.31506|
|WindowsBase.dll|5.00.821.31506|
```

Although some libraries are forced to load by reflexion using assembly resolver they are correctly discovered.

Do you have any tips what i need to check?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience and found this reference

https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/851

Which unfortunately only appears to refer to the idea of not mixing versions of .NET